# Creating External HTTP(S) Load Balancer on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create an External HTTP(S) Load Balancer on Google Cloud Platform to perform the function of a reverse proxy.

It will act as a single entry point and then allow me to have different services at different routes. e.g a static site hosted on Storage as well as another resource hosted at an external location.

The [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) seems to suggest this is possible but when I go to create a load balancer I only see the following options neither of which appear to support external locations/acting as a proxy.

- HTTP(S) load balancing

  - Global HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)
  - Global HTTP(S) load balancer
  - Regional HTTP(S) load balancer

Any insights on how to achieve this?

Edit: I've realised that a Hybrid connectivity network endpoint group allows you to connect to an external IP:port combo. Is there a solution for where we don't have an IP:port but rather a URL for example an s3 bucket or other hosted website?

Comment: What did you try? Do you have screenshot to share?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, sorry I missed out what I had tried. I have updated the post now

Comment: Did you try and internet NEG as backend service?